# Adding 1600x900 screen resolution

Tags: nvidia, display, resolution, vmware

I am new to Ubuntu. I have a Dell 17r se laptop with 1600x900 resolution. I use vmware to run Ubuntu 14.04 Lts on Windows 8.1 using Vmware. I have hd4000 and Nvidia 650m gpu in my laptop. Now the problem is there is no 1600x900 resolution in Ubuntu. And it cant detect my display. I tried many solutions available in the internet and found this one working best for me.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966900

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode Virtual1 "1600x900_60.00"

xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode "1600x900_60.00"
```

Once i type the above code in terminal, resolution changes to 1600x900 but when i power off my os and start it again then my resolution is back to 1440x900.

How do i make sure that the above code run after boot ?

Also in the source of the code its written that i need to add this code in

```
/etc/gdm/Init/Default
```

so that it loads everytime but i couldnt find gdm folder.

Comment: As you are running Ubuntu within Vmware, is your VM also able to do the same resolution ? Your problem is maybe with the configuration of the Virtual graphic adapter.

Comment: The Gnome Display Manager (GDM) was replaced with LightDM a few releases back, so you should search for guides that are more up to date.

Comment: Virtual1 doesn't worked for me  and I found some other names on internet with same command.

and I ended with 'eDP-1' instead,  for dell i5 7th-gen 3568 laptop. that is having maximum 1366x768 resolution by default